# Memory leak in pandas: how to fix function that returns a subset of rows from a DataFrame without garbage-cleaning the dropped rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory-leaks

I believe this is related to this question: [Why does deleting columns or parts of a DataFrame increase memory usage, and how to ensure garbage collection on unused slices of DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68015094/why-does-deleting-columns-or-parts-of-a-dataframe-increase-memory-usage-and-how)

I'm running pandas 1.1.5 (but issue also happens on 1.5.1).

#### The problem

For a self-contained reproducible example, see: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/49582

I've noticed a memory issue when I generate and filter large DataFrames, where data I've filtered out still seems to take up space in memory. Imagine the following example:

```
def get_data() -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Return a large DataFrame"""
    return db_connection.read_sql(query)  # get dataframe from some database

def get_filtered_data():
    """Return a small DataFrame"""
    df = get_data()
    df["new_col"] = df.apply(some_func)   # some operation on the other columns
    return df[df.new_col < some_value]    # returns a small subset
```

where I might be calling `get_filtered_data()` in a loop with some args, and where only a small subset of the full DataFrame is returned (let's say 100 out of the original 200k rows).

The issue is that after calling `filtered_data = get_filtered_data()`, my memory usage is very high, as though I was still using memory for the original 200k row DataFrame. I can do `filtered_data.memory_usage()` and it doesn't match at all the memory usage of my python process.

**Also, the total recursive memory usage of my `globals()` and `locals()` of my python process is drastically different from the total memory usage of my globals() - several MB vs 25 GB.** Note that here I mean the "deep" memory usage, and not just getsizeof.

It seems that the rows that I select out from the DataFrame aren't being garbage-collected.

---

#### Attempted solutions

I tried a few solutions, including:

```
def get_filtered_data():
    """Return a small DataFrame"""
    df = get_data()
    df["new_col"] = df.apply(some_func)         # some operation on the other columns
    return df[df.new_col < some_value].copy()
```

where I was expecting that since I'm no longer returning a view, it should be clear to the interpreter that nothing is referencing the original unfiltered DataFrame. But I still see large memory usage.

I also tried:

```
def get_filtered_data():
    """Return a small DataFrame"""
    df = get_data()
    df["new_col"] = df.apply(some_func)         # some operation on the other columns
    out = df[df.new_col < some_value].copy()
    del df
    gc.collect()
    return out
```

And this doesn't seem to work.

---

#### The question

I would like to know

1. What is the recommended way of doing what I'm trying to do above without causing a memory leak?
2. Is there any documentation that explains what's happening above and why we get a memory leak? Is this related to views or something else?

Comment: I reccomnd pandas official bug report page to search similar case solution or post question here...I've seen similar issue recently here  --> https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues

Comment: I posted the issue here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/49582

This also contains a much better reproducible example.

Comment: Excellent...It's really so detailed...Developers will dig into that!!!